# `contentOffset` animation performance: `CABasicAnimation` vs UIView Animation Blocks vs `Timer` with manual set

Tags: ios, animation, uiscrollview, uikit, core-animation

I want to constantly, infinitely animate UIScrollView's `contentOffset`.

I have 4 options:

- set off a `Timer` 60 times per second and manually set contentOffset without explicit animation
- create a single `CABasicAnimation`
- animate using a single call to `UIView.animate`
- use UIViewPropertyAnimator

Question: are there any favorites in terms of minimizing CPU strain?

My assumption is that basically 95% of resource will be used on re-rendering. All of these methods will involve setting contentOffset and rerendering the scene. The only difference will really be the trigger. In one case, it will be a literal Timer, while in the others it will be `CADisplayLink`.

I am right in assuming that it will barely make any difference?
Is `Timer` approach somehow radically worse than proper animations?